# Kill external process on pythonw.exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

In Python, external processes can be started easily using the `subprocess` module. For instance on Windows:

```
command = 'external_app'
my_process = subprocess.Popen(
    command,
    creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,
    shell=True,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True)
```

To kill the process, we can run:

```
os.kill(my_process.pid, signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)
```

This works fine using the command-line interpreter of Python (`python.exe`). But if I like to start and stop processes from within a graphical Python application without a command-line window using `pythonw.exe` the problem occurs that I can’t stop the process with `os.kill` anymore.

How can I kill an external process on Windows with `pythonw.exe`?

Comment: Use `my_process.kill()`

Comment: But if you want to really interrupt instead of killing, then you need to allocate a console: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43469445/261181