# How to interrupt Python subprocesses on Windows when using Python C API?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, interrupt

I'm able to interrupt my subprocesses in Windows with

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.kernel32.GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(1, _proc.pid)
```

but only if I run it via normal Python process.

When I run the same code via a separate launcher program using Python C API (code is below), the code above doesn't have any effect.

Should I change my launcher somehow in order to be able to interrupt subprocesses?

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    LPWSTR *argv;
    int argc;

    argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLine(), &argc);
    if (argv == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Unable to parse command line", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return 10;
    }

    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();
    PySys_SetArgvEx(argc, argv, 0);

    PyObject *py_main, *py_dict;
    py_main = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
    py_dict = PyModule_GetDict(py_main);

    PyObject* result = PyRun_String(
        "from runpy import run_module\n"
        "run_module('thonny')\n",
        Py_file_input,
        py_dict,
        py_dict
        );

    int code;
    if (!result) {
        PyObject *ptype, *pvalue, *ptraceback;
        PyErr_Fetch(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback);

        PyObject* valueAsString = PyObject_Str(pvalue);

        wchar_t* error_msg = PyUnicode_AsWideCharString(valueAsString, NULL);
        MessageBox(0, error_msg, L"Thonny startup error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        code = -1;
    }
    else {
        code = 1;
    }

    Py_Finalize();

    return code;
}
```

EDIT: Turns out the same problems comes with `pythonw.exe`.

Comment: Unless the target `pid` is actually a process *group* ID, as is documented, then the behavior of `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_BREAK_EVENT, pid)` is undefined. In practice what it does is act like `pid` is 0, i.e. it broadcasts the event to every process that's attached to a console. You don't want that. It could kill a parent process that's attached to the console.

Comment: As to your launcher, it isn't attached to a console at all, so I can't see why you would think `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` would work.

Comment: Your best bet is to use real IPC, for example a named event object.  (Granted, I have no idea how to do that in Python.)

Comment: @eryksun , I'm creating the process with `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`, so it works with normal Python. Any ideas, how to attach the launcher to a console?

Comment: @eryksun , The launcher is a GUI process, which uses python.exe to run background tasks. When I run my module via Eclipse Pydev, then no console window is seen but I can interrupt the backend. When I run it via my launcher, then console window pops up for backend, but I can't interrupt it.

Comment: @eryksun , yes, I'm doing `signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, signal_handler)`.

Comment: @eryksun , I could get the console with AllocConsole (together with unfortunate console window), but I failed with AttachConsole. I edited my question to show what I tried. Can you spot what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

That's how I finally got the console allocated without flashing console window (thanks to @eryksun for the pointers):

```
import sys
import ctypes
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

cmd = [sys.executable, "-c", "print('Hi!'); input()"]
child = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                         shell=True)

child.stdout.readline() # now I know subprocess is ready
result = kernel32.AttachConsole(child.pid)
if not result:
    err = ctypes.get_last_error()
    print("Could not allocate console. Error code:", err, file=sys.stderr)
child.stdin.write(b"\n") # allow subprocess to complete
child.stdin.flush()
```

Basically I stole the console from a dummy subprocess.

Comment: If you're going to use the cmd shell, you can do it more reliably than with timeouts. Have the shell echo to stdout and read from stdin. The parent reads from the child's stdout, attaches to the console, and closes stdin. For example:

Comment: `child = subprocess.Popen('echo & set /p "x="', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True);` `child.stdout.read(1);` `result = kernel32.AttachConsole(child.pid);` `child.stdin.close();` `if child.poll() is None: child.kill()`

Comment: In case anyone is wondering how the console is hidden in this case, the `shell=True` argument runs the command via `%ComSpec% /c` (typically cmd.exe) and *also* sets the `STARTUPINFO` to hide the window.

Comment: Thanks, @eryksun! I edited the answer according to your suggestion.

Comment: Oops, fixed now

Comment: It's a bad idea to pass an args list with `shell=True`. It has to be converted to a string via `subprocess.list2cmdline`, but this only works correctly for running programs that use VC++ rules to create `argv` for `[w]main`. cmd.exe has its own rules, which are quirky enough as is, but that gets compounded by the parsing rules of the program you're invoking via the shell, such as python.exe. This can get complicated. Reliably automating it would be hard. Thus for shell commands it's best to use a tested command-line passed as a string. The same goes for Unix, but for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I'll propose one possible solution according to @eryksun's comment.

Just do

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.kernel32.AllocConsole()
```

in parent process.

Unfortunately (as eryksun also noted), this also creates unnecessary and confusing console window.

Comment: If you're doing it this way, you can hide the console using `user32.ShowWindow(kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE)`. BTW, please define prototypes, starting with your own instances of the libraries, i.e. `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)` and using `ctypes.get_last_error()` to check the captured error value.